# Using existing C/C++ code in Metro App

Tags: c++, linker, microsoft-metro

i want to use existing C/C++ Code in a Metro App. I've made a "Blank App (XAML)", include my header files etc. Everything is compiling fine, but the linker doens't find my functions and global variables that i need to initalize my stuff.  I've ported my code to many platforms like iOS, Android and other without any problem linker problems.

I think the "Blank App (XAML)" project is using managed C++ is this correct? is there any trick to use unmanaged C/C++ code in managed C++? Any other idea?

Thank you in advance!
Best Mario

Comment: Could you please post the complete log VS gave you when trying to build solution? It might help.

Comment: The "etc" part is important.  Your header files provide only the declarations of your existing C/C++ code, you also need the sources that provide the implementation (or the lib to link in, or the DLL to ship inside your appx).


What you are attempting is entirely possible, though (I've seen the native C++ physics library Bullet ported successfully).  And all Metro projects for C++ are C++/CX which is a NATIVE (not managed) projection of WinRT for C++, and is fully compatible with native C/C++.